# Incorrectly routing /index to /show in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There must be an obvious answer to this, but I'm at a loss.

I have a Rails app which tracks sites. For whatever reason, localhost:3000/sites leads to my index page. However, localhost:3000/sites/index leads to my show page.

Why is this?

Below is the routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :sites
```

Below is the sites controller:

```
class SitesController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

end
```

In views/sites, there is the index.html.erb and show.html.erb files. The former displays at /sites, the latter displays at /sites/index (and /sites/show as one would expect).

Thanks for any help!

UPDATE:

When I rake routes, I get:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
sites GET    /sites(.:format)          sites#index
      POST   /sites(.:format)          sites#create
new_site GET    /sites/new(.:format)      sites#new
edit_site GET    /sites/:id/edit(.:format) sites#edit
 site GET    /sites/:id(.:format)      sites#show
      PATCH  /sites/:id(.:format)      sites#update
      PUT    /sites/:id(.:format)      sites#update
      DELETE /sites/:id(.:format)      sites#destroy
```

These routes are what one would expect, but I guess I'm just surprised that sites/index presumes index is an :id and therefore routes the request to show.

I suppose I had never explicitly encountered that behavior before.

Answer (score 4):

There are 7 basic actions in a controller by default, only 2 of them are matched by name in the url - (`new` and `edit`). These 2 are HTML constructs, they are just a way of rendering a form.

The other 5 (index, show, update, create, destroy) are the more basic routes and do the work to display and modify resources.  They are referenced by only *two* url patterns (the two patterns you mentioned above - eg '/sites' and '/sites/:id').  They are differentiated by the *method* that goes along with the request: (Patch, Post, Get, Delete).  So, "/sites" would be used for `create` and `index`.  "/sites/:id" would be used for `show`, `destroy`, and `update`.

The action in the controller is not referenced by the url exactly - the url pattern and the request method together are used to call the associated controller method.

In the request "/sites/index", as the string "index" is in the url, the only route that matches is one that has a variable after "/sites/".  `:id` is just a variable, not necessarily an integer.  Since the request was a GET, the first (and only) route match is `sites#show`.  "index" will be the value of `params[:id]` passed into the show action.

Answer (score 3):

This is the way routing works in Rails. Take a look at [Rails routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to get a better understanding of how this works. Especially the 
[Rails resource routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) section.

Generally when you setup a resource route as you did the urls would be as follows:

```
example.com/sites #=> index page
example.com/sites/:id #=> show page. A specific site, where :id would be the unique identifier

# Here's an example URL with a specific site
example.com/sites/stackoverflow
```

Answer (score 2):

Your index page is at: `localhost:3000/sites`

Navigate to `localhost:3000/rails/info/routes` to see your full app routes in development mode.